# Entity framework and ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Using ASP.NET MVC 5 and Entity Framework 6, I am trying to save a new record `Package` to the database. I have the following model entities:

User.cs (`ApplicationUser` in the default template)

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    private ICollection<Package> packages;

    public User()
    {
        this.packages = new HashSet<Package>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Package> Packages
    {
        get { return this.packages; }
        set { this.packages = value; }
    }

    ...
}
```

Package.cs

```
public class Package
{
    private ICollection<User> maintainers;

    public Package()
    {
        this.maintainers = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    [Required]
    public virtual ICollection<User> Maintainers
    {
        get
        {
            return this.maintainers;
        }

        set
        {
            this.maintainers = value;
        }
    }
    
    ...
}
```

I have the following DbContext class:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>, IApplicationDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public virtual IDbSet<Package> Packages { get; set; }

    ...

    public static ApplicationDbContextCreate()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

I also have PackageService.cs (similar to the service pattern):

```
public class PackagesService : IPackagesService
{
    private readonly IRepository<Package> packages;

    public PackagesService(IRepository<Package> packages)
    {
        this.packages = packages;
    }


    public Package Create(IList<User> maintainers)
    {
        var newPackage = new Package
        {
            Maintainers = maintainers
        };

        this.packages.Add(newPackage);
        this.packages.SaveChanges();

        return newPackage;
    }
}
```

I also have standard implementation of IRepository as a GenericRepository: [source code here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d0194b0cf0b29052f1b2).

Now the problem I'm having is that when the `Create()` method is called Entity Framework throws the following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

I understand that the problem is that the `Package` entity is change-tracked by two different DbContexts, but I use the same `ApplicationDbContext` through the entire application. Moreover, here's how I inject it (using Ninject):

```
kernel.Bind<DbContext>().To<ApplicationDbContext>().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(GenericRepository<>));
kernel.Bind<IUserStore<User>>().To<UserStore<User>>().WithConstructorArgument("context", kernel.Get<DbContext>());
kernel.Bind<UserManager<User>>().ToSelf();
```

This is the part that confuses me the most. Not only do I bind the context with Ninject, but wherever I use i.e `UserManager`, I get it through the Owin instance, which creates it with the Create() static method of exactly the same DbContext. So how could there be two DbContext instances?

I've spent the whole day debugging this and I can't understand why it's happening. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your class definition says `ApplicationDbContext` but then in your ninject config `kernel.Bind<DbContext>().To<LinuxPackagesDbContext>().InRequestScope();` Can you clarify this

Comment: Fixed, it was a mistake with the copy pasting.

Comment: @arnaudoff Maybe remove the question or write what the problem was in the answer

Comment: Is it possible that when you pass maintainers `public Package Create(IList<User> maintainers)` that it is coming from another context somehow? Try commenting out `Maintainers = maintainers` to see if that is the problem. At least that can help you narrow down

Comment: @b1tsh1ft, well, removing that line seemed to remove the issue, but that doesn't fix the problem. Maintainers comes from `this.UserManager.Users`, where the `UserManager` property is exactly like the one from `ManageController.cs` in the default MVC template that comes when you create a new project, hence the context is fetched from the Owin pipeline.

Comment: I think InRequestScope comes from Ninject.Web.Common, but in order for it to work with MVC you also need Ninject.MVC5 package. Did you install that? Somehow Ninject doesn't seem to be reusing the created Context in the request scope.

Comment: Yes, I'm using it. In fact, only these lines are what's different between my NinjectWebCommon.cs and the default one from Ninject.MVC5.

Comment: There seems to be musings that InRequestScope doesn't work with OWIN properly afters some Googling, do a search and you'll see. You may be better off using a different injector library. Also, are you doing MVC (Controller) or WebAPI (ApiController). There is a ninject webapi library you need if you have the latter  in your project.

Comment: But in Startup.Auth.cs these two statements `app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);` and             `app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);` imply that when I do `this.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();` the DbContext would be the same, don't they? More to the point, the `ApplicationUserManager` is instantiated with `new UserStore<User>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>())` as an argument. How would this result in a different context, even without using Ninject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether the problem was the DI bindings and Ninject in particular, but I managed to find a workaround. Since apparently I had two instances of a DbContext, instead of using the records from the first one I mapped the many-to-many relationship with the primary keys only. Something along the following lines:

```
if (maintainerIds != null && maintainerIds.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (string maintainerId in maintainerIds)
    {
        var maintainer = new User() { Id = maintainerId };
        users.Attach(maintainer);
        newPackage.Maintainers.Add(maintainer);
    }
}
```

This basically doesn't even require a DbContext as long as the ids match.